# How to write a loop that doubles an int based on a condition

Tags: python

100,000 satoshies = 0.001 btc

```
somethingRandom(btc):
       #code

btc = 0.001
satoshies = btc / 0.00000001


if somethingRandom():
         #double 
         somethingRandom(btc)
else:
         #reset
          somethingRandom(btc)
```

If `somethingRandom` returns true, I want to keep on doubling the amount of satoshies, by doubling the amount of btc

If it returns false, I want to reset the btc to 0.001

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: By adding btc as an argument to the function, you are changing the nature of the question, and you are doing it inconsistently. You should revert your question to what was originally asked.

Comment: I would suggest that you need to be more specific about what you want if you think you need to change your question.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
def somethingRandom():
  return random.choice((True, False))

btc = 0.001

while True:
  if somethingRandom():
    btc *= 2
  else:
    btc = 0.001
    satoshies = btc / 0.00000001
```

Comment: if somethingRandom() returned true 3 times in a row, it would have to double (0.001 * 2) 3 times, so the value of the btc would be 0.008. I believe your code resets the btc to 0.001 since you assign the value to 0.001 right after somethingRandom(). I've edited my main post. my fault.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would implement a random binomial (True or False) function:

```
def binomial(p=.5):
    '''return True with probability p, else False with probability 1-p'''
    return random.random() < p
```

And here's what I would do to implement what you say you want:

```
btc = 0.001
def satoshies():  # needs to be in a function, because recalculating based on btc change:
    return btc / 0.00000001


if somethingRandom():
    btc *= 2
else:
    btc = .001

satoshies()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you enjoy using `itertools`:

```
import itertools

btc *= 2**(sum(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: somethingRandom(), itertools.repeat(1))))
```